# HTTPS website accessing HTTP WCF service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, https

I have deployed an MVC web application on IIS, and it is configured to run over HTTPS.
Further, the website is consuming a WCF service which is deployed on other server (in same network). The WCF service is running over HTTP. 
Everything seems working fine, but while accessing the website it is always giving following message on IE 8.

[image: See the image]

How can we make the site accessible without the below message getting displayed? Also, the solution should not entail any changes at client-level. I need a solution which can be done at site-level.

Comment: Have you done any investigation as to why this is happening?

Comment: There are two environments. It works without this message on staging environment where both website and WCF are running on HTTP, whereas it gives this prompt where the website is running on HTTPS, and WCF on HTTP.

Comment: If you are calling the WCF service from client script then the error is just warning the user of mixed content mode. I would suggest you change the binding for the WCF service and call that over ssl. If its important enough for the site to be running over ssl surely this also goes for the wcf service?

Comment: @SCB - please write this as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it seems that you have enabled https and want to consume service vai http. so please change your serviceMetadata

```
<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
```

to

```
 <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken this will only enable/disable access of the services metadata of http/https. This does not effect if the service will communicate over http/https

Comment: would you please add your web.config file ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the WCF service from client script then the error is just warning the user of mixed content mode.

I would suggest you change the binding for the WCF service and call that over ssl. If its important enough for the site to be running over ssl surely this also goes for the wcf service?